# Evaluate $-\int \frac{dy}{y}$

Tags: integration

$$-\int \frac{dy}{y}$$ My answer was $-\ln(y)+c$ but my professor said it should be $\ln(\frac{c}{y})$ I tried to simplify it more but just end up with $\ln\frac{1}{y}+c$ how did the $C$ became the numerator?

Comment: We need absolute values on $y$ to be precise.  Please reference my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Both forms are fine. Your professors form is simply obtained from yours by $$\ln \frac 1y+C=\ln \frac 1y+\ln e^C=\ln\frac {e^C}y=\ln\frac{c_1}y$$
Also, $-\ln y=\ln y^{-1}=\ln \frac 1y$

Comment: There's an equals sign in that first line which is horribly wrong - you still need the $\ln$

Comment: Still missing the $\ln$ in one place.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\log(a)+\log(b)=\log(ab)$

Answer (score 2):

we know that $\ln \frac{a}{b}=\ln a-\ln b$

so
$$-\int \frac{dy}{y}=-\ln y +k$$

assume $k=\ln C $ to get
$$-\int \frac{dy}{y}=-\ln y +\ln C=\ln \frac{C}{y}$$

Answer (score 2):

The complete answer is

$$I=-\int \frac{dy}{y}=-\ln |y|+C$$

Inasmuch as we have $-\ln x=\ln (1/x)$, then $I$ can be expressed as

$$I=\ln \left|\frac{1}{y}\right|+C=\ln \left|\frac{C'}{y}\right|$$

where $\ln |C'|= C$.

The absolute value is important here.  For example, suppose we attempt to evaluate $-\int_{-2}^{-1}\frac{dy}{y}$ as $-\ln(-1)+\ln(-2)$. If we are restricted to real analysis, then these terms don't exist.  However, we know from symmetry that the result should be $\ln 2-\log 1=\ln 2$.  Upon using the appropriate anti-derivative equipped with the absolute values, we obtain

$$-\int_{-2}^{-1}\frac{dy}{y}=\left.\left(-\ln|y|\right)\,\right|_{-2}^{-1}=-\ln|-1|+\ln|-2|=\ln 2$$

as expected!

Comment: Since the OP is likely in an introductory Calculus 1 course, it helps to use $\ln$ instead of $\log$, since lower-division college math conventions dictate $\ln$ is $\log_e$ and $\log$ is $\log_{10}$. Using $\log$ in place of $\ln$ can potentially become really confusing for the OP.

Comment: @dragon Thanks for the suggestion.  And good catch.  I've edited accordingly.